# Why doesn't an SQL query load a table fully sometimes?

Tags: mysql, loading, create-table

```
CREATE TABLE Food_journal (f_entry_number INT NOT NULL, date DATE, type VARCHAR(40), 
fat_g DECIMAL(5,1), carb_g DECIMAL(5,1),
protein_g DECIMAL(5,1), alcohol_g DECIMAL(5,1), calories INT, pssn INT,
PRIMARYKEY(f_entry_number), FOREIGN KEY(pssn) REFERENCES Patient(ssn));    

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/0/hemeyerj/CSE3241/food_journal.txt' INTO TABLE Food_journal;
```

food_journal.txt:

```
1   2013-01-27  carrots 0   15  3   0   72  142969229   
2   2013-02-25  meat    3   0   24  0   124 825324470   
1   2013-01-27  meat    5   0   32  0   173 142969299   
1   2013-02-14  fruit   0   20  1   0   84  507663448   
1   2013-04-01  twinky  4.5 27  1   0   150 812654040
```

It only loads the first two rows into the table. I've checked tabs and even completely retyped the thing, but it doesn't work. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the first column, f_entry_number, is set as the PRIMARYKEY which means it must be unique. The 3rd row that gets entered has a value of 1 which has already been used on the first row, so it fails. Try changing your f_entry_number's to be unique.